# Programming Gradient Descent

Tags: python

I'm trying to program gradient descent for my class,we use google colab for programming projects. I'm not sure where my code is going wrong, In python

```
import numpy as np
#Parameters
lamb= 0.1
beta = 1
alpha = 1
#Label at z is +1 and -z is -1
#Optimal w = z / ||z||^2 and b = 0
z = np.array([1,2])
#Data Matrix and Labels
x = np.vstack((z,-z))
y = np.array([1,-1])
#Random Initialization
w = np.array([-0.34637426,  1.16720011])
b = np.array([-0.24424188])
m=len(z)
sumw=0
sumb=0
#Insert your code here to compute the gradients and loss. You can
#Use as many additional lines of code as needed (i.e., don't try too
#hard to put the whole computation in one line)
for i in range(1000):
  for j in range(m):
    sumb+=(y[j])/(1+np.exp((-beta)*(1-y[j]*(x[j]@w-b))))
    sumw+=(y[j]*x[j])/(1+np.exp((-beta)*(1-y[j]*(x[j]@w-b))))
  grad_w = 2 * lamb * w - (1/2)*sumw
  grad_b=(1/m)*sumb
  b-=alpha*grad_b
  w-=alpha*grad_w
  if i % 100 == 0:
        print(w,' ', b)
```

The problem is this [Problem 4 iii)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttnEm.png)

This is what I'm getting

```
[-0.00311842  1.48172206]   [-0.19604564]
[2.52108931 5.04217862]   [5.53009896]
[2.7530958  5.50619161]   [3.85357184]
[2.76527666 5.53055331]   [0.82437199]
[2.76756568 5.53513137]   [-2.25691088]
[2.79916861 5.59833721]   [-5.09974894]
[2.93920254 5.87840507]   [-6.08686155]
[3.00843697 6.01687395]   [-4.78457688]
[3.01993034 6.03986068]   [-2.86787546]
[3.02152889 6.04305778]   [-0.86030793]
```

This is what I should be getting.

```
[-0.34637426  1.16720011] [-0.24424188] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-3.17437461e-06] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-4.60193897e-11] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-5.82867088e-16] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-1.94289029e-16] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-1.94289029e-16] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-1.94289029e-16] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-1.94289029e-16] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-1.94289029e-16] 
[0.5989022  1.19780439]  [-1.94289029e-16]
```

Is the problem with my sum?

Comment: Please post some OS and Python version info.

Comment: Also, please don't put yourself down in your posts! "I suck at programming"?! That just gives other SO users the chance to put your work down more.  Just post your code and what you've tried and ***not*** how bad you are at it (if you even are)! 

Comment: For the class we use https://colab.research.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `sumw` and `sumb` inside the first for loop so they wont accumulate the values over and over again.

Should look like this:

```
import numpy as np
#Parameters
lamb= 0.1
beta = 1
alpha = 1
#Label at z is +1 and -z is -1
#Optimal w = z / ||z||^2 and b = 0
z = np.array([1,2])
#Data Matrix and Labels
x = np.vstack((z,-z))
y = np.array([1,-1])
#Random Initialization
w = np.array([-0.34637426,  1.16720011])
b = np.array([-0.24424188])
m=len(z)
#Insert your code here to compute the gradients and loss. You can
#Use as many additional lines of code as needed (i.e., don't try too
#hard to put the whole computation in one line)
for i in range(1000):
  sumw=0
  sumb=0
  for j in range(m):
    sumb+=(y[j])/(1+np.exp((-beta)*(1-y[j]*(x[j]@w-b))))
    sumw+=(y[j]*x[j])/(1+np.exp((-beta)*(1-y[j]*(x[j]@w-b))))
  grad_w = 2 * lamb * w - (1/2)*sumw
  grad_b=(1/m)*sumb
  b-=alpha*grad_b
  w-=alpha*grad_w
  if i % 100 == 0:
        print(w,' ', b)
```